# batch file to loop x amount of times adding each number to the end of a string

Tags: windows, batch-file

environment windows domain
prefer answer in way of a batch file

we are currently setting up 100+ new computers and i don't mind doing a loop and entering in the name of the computer each time, but i would LOVE to have a batch file i only have to type a few letters and BAM done.

see our naming scheme is something like: bar01, bar02, bar03 for the computers

here is what i would like to do:
i have two variables to prompt the user.
 1. computer name
 2. number of computers

start a loop that will run the amount of times equal to the numbers of computers
while also adding each of those numbers to the end of the computer name variable

(i know this likely isn't the correct syntax, but it is so i can, hopefully, show what i'm attempting to accomplish)

```
set /p cname=computer name:
set /p x=amount of computers:

for /l %%n in (1, 1,%x%) do {
 xcopy "%~dp0Microsoft Word 2010.lnk" "\\%cname%%x%\c$\users\desktop\word.lnk"
}
```

i hope that is understandable, and i am not sure if the title is detailed enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
set /p cname=computer name:
set /p x=amount of computers:

for /l %%n in (1, 1,%x%) do (
 echo %cname%%%n)
```

If you need the leading 0 (from 01 to 09) :

```
@echo off
set /p cname=computer name:
set /p x=amount of computers:

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%n in (1, 1,%x%) do (
 set "$Nb=%%n"
 if !$Nb! lss 10 set $Nb=0!$Nb!
 echo %cname%!$Nb!)
```

Comment: You are right, i started my solution using `delayedexpansion` but at the end it wasn't necessary.

Comment: on the echo %cname%!$Nb! line, if i need to had a few lines of code in there all i have to do is make sure the ) is moved to the end of the last line and everything within the () will run, correct?

Comment: Yes, everything that have to run inside the `FOR` loop. Like youx `Xcopy`